# ReactJS - Axios doesn't return data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have this code to get data with Axios. Unfortunately, this code is not working because the `console.log(response);` is not logging any data in the console. What is wrong here? Is there something missing?

```
const ROOT_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

const getFindAll = (data) => {
  return {
    type: constants.FETCH_FIND_ALL,
    payload: data
  }
}

export const fetchFindAll = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios({
      method: 'put',
      url: `${ROOT_URL}/posts/1`
    })
      .then(response => {
       console.log(response);
        dispatch(getFindAll(response.data.Body.Message));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        //TODO: handle the error when implemented
      })
  }
}
```

I'm calling the `fetchFindAll()` inside `FileTree` component:

```
export class FileTree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { activeNode: null };
    console.log('ldirj', props)

    this.setActiveNode = this.setActiveNode.bind(this);
  }

  setActiveNode(name) {
    this.setState({ activeNode: name });
    this.props.liftStateUp(name);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ searchTerm }) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm });
  }

    renderFindAll () {
      const fetch = this.props.fetchFindAll();
      fetch(this.props.dispatch);
      console.log(fetch);
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.renderFindAll();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="grid__item-50">
        {renderTree(this.props.root, this.setActiveNode, this.state.activeNode, null, this.state.searchTerm)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace `//TODO: handle the error when implemented` with something that handles errors

Comment: Look at the Console. It might not log the data, but it might log some other error message.

Comment: Look at the Network Tab in the browser's developer tools. Is the request sent? Is the request formatted the way you expect? Does it get a response? Is the response the one you expect?

Comment: @Quentin I checked the network tab, and there is nothing there related to the request I trying to do.

Comment: @Quentin and I found no errors :/

Comment: You never actually call the function in the code you've provided.

Comment: How so? @Quentin

Comment: You define a function stored in the variable `fetchFindAll`. I don't see `fetchFindAll()` for a start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174119/discussion-between-rcohen-and-quentin).

Comment: Let's not. You should edit your question to include a real [mcve]. (That or actually call the function you are creating).

Comment: Try running just the axios command and console.log(response.data) w/o anything else, do you get the expected data?

Comment: @Quentin I updated the code

Comment: @K.F there's a `console.log` in the response, but doesn't show any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `fetchFindAll()` will give you a closure function.

To actually trigger the request, you need to invoke it with `fetchFindAll()(dispatch)`

`fetchFindAll` does not accept any argument, therefore, passing `this.state` to it won't make any difference.

Also, calling `fetchFindAll` multiple times will give you multiple closure functions.

In conclusion, you should do something like this:

```
renderFindAll () {
  const fetch = this.props.fetchFindAll();
  fetch(this.props.dispatch); // assuming you are using react-redux
}
```

---- EDIT ----

Try to implement `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.renderFindAll();
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code with your solution, and it's still not working, unfortunately. @kit

Comment: But yes, I am using `react-redux`; @kit

Comment: You should not put `renderFindAll` in `render`, you are just rendering it to your DOM, not calling it. If you want to trigger it as soon as the component is rendered, you need to implement `componentDidMount` in `FileTree`.

Comment: You are right. `renderFindAll ` inside `render()` was just for testing. Even so, `console.log(response)` inside `fetchFindAll()` is not even logging. This means axios is not getting anything, correct? @kit

Comment: The request doesn't appear inside the Network tab, on dev tools. @kit

Comment: You have never actually invoked `renderFindAll` in your component life cycle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174124/discussion-between-rcohen-and-kit).

Answer (score 0):

> this.props.fetchFindAll(this.state)

Calling this function does nothing except return a function (`(dispatch) => { ... }`) (which you ignore).

You need to either call the returned function or rewrite `fetchFindAll` so it does the work of `(dispatch) => { ... }` itself.

The latter option is probably the better one, as you aren't passing any variables that you could be closing over.

Comment: I called the returned function, but it's still not returning any data. @Quentin

Comment: According to your latest edit, you now don't even call `fetchFindAll` let alone do anything with its return value.

Comment: Then this means I didn't completely understood your answer. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it sounds like some react/react-redux things are tripping you up here.  I had some time and so I went ahead and modeled how this might work together here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/8n9vvz6lx9
(I didn't setup any reducers/state vars - you should see the response in devtools - console)

I'll try not to go in detail on info you can find in the docs (which are a really great resource, along with the tutorials you can find linked there).

Redux docs: https://redux.js.org/

If you have trouble understanding the react component architecture, react docs & tutorials are plenty as well. (https://reactjs.org/) I assume you're already looking at these.

Redux is really powerful but can be a bit confusing, so I'll attempt to detail the things I've noticed in the code you've provided (keeping in mind that you might know some of these things and you may not have included them in your code here)

1: `dispatch` needs to come from somewhere, react-redux offers `connect` (https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux):

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// ...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  dispatch
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(FileTree);
```

2: Your action should also be imported somewhere:

```
import { fetchFindAll } from "../actions";

// ...

renderFindAll() {
    const fetch = fetchFindAll();
    fetch(this.props.dispatch);
    console.log(fetch);
}
```

3: For most components, you want to `export default` depending on how you plan to import.

4: In general you can use a put method here, but you're probably more likely wanting to use `axios.get('${URL}')`

5: Take a look at the response data you're getting (using a put request):
[image: response]

Inside of `response.data` is `{id: 1}` so calling `response.data.Body.Message` will error.  It's very likely that you wanted to use a get request here which would give you this:

[image]

which still doesn't have a `response.data.Body.Message`, but maybe that's closer to what you intended.

Okay, really hope this helps! Good luck!